# one letter FOR ALL BUT different color

Tags: excel, vba

I want each Cell value starts with a letter A,B,C... to be colored a certain color.

I can do that only if it says only A it works.
What needs to be fixed?

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Left(Target.Value, 1) = "A" Then Target.Interior.Color = 34
If Left(Target.Value, 1) = "B" Then Target.Interior.Color = 36
If Left(Target.Value, 1) = "C" Then Target.Interior.Color = 39
If Left(Target.Value, 1) = "D" Then Target.Interior.Color = 41
If Left(Target.Value, 1) = "E" Then Target.Interior.Color = 38
If Left(Target.Value, 1) = "F" Then Target.Interior.Color = 37
If Left(Target.Value, 1) = "G" Then Target.Interior.Color = 35

End Sub
```

Comment: `If left(Target.Value,1) = "A" Then ...`

Comment: You know you do not need VBA for this? You can achieve this with conditional formatting? :)

Answer (score 0):

your macro works but colors are same. use interior.colorindex property

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Left(Target.Value, 1) = "A" Then Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
   If Left(Target.Value, 1) = "B" Then Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
   If Left(Target.Value, 1) = "C" Then Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
   If Left(Target.Value, 1) = "D" Then Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
   If Left(Target.Value, 1) = "E" Then Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
   If Left(Target.Value, 1) = "F" Then Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
   If Left(Target.Value, 1) = "G" Then Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 7
End Sub
```

there u have [palete](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm)

Comment: @sari: If an answer solved your problem, our rule here is to tick the code left check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**...